# Designing an RPC style architecture to perform queries to individual clients

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am about to figure out functionality of rabbitmq.

Lets say that i have 10 clients and each client have a database which is behind firewall or some other security layer (so there is no way to access data in database directly).

Now how will it be possible to receive data from database at each client using rabbitMQ?

My thought is to create a rabbitmq server and a listener. Each client will have a copy of that listener. So to retreive data from the client i will send a message to client's listener and wait for response.

But i cant figure out how to implement the wait for response part? As i understand i will need to implement RPC call, but that means that each client will need a queue of it own?

Did anyone implemented such functionality?

Comment: I don't think the question is broad, just because it doesn't contain any code. Maybe it could have been marketed better including a nice picture, but the description of the use case is fine in order to design a proper architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to address individual clients.

You could do it with dedicated queues as you stated. In such a design your clients will be allowed to reply to the requests even if offline: once they start and connect to RabbitMQ, they will find the requests and answer to them.

Viceversa, if you want to let the client reply only if online, I would choose a different approach: use a topic exchange and let each client bind with a temporary queue and consume messages that match the published topic - for example the topic could be (or could contain) the hostname of the client: only the addressed client will consume it.

In both cases the clients will need to reply to the requests. The simplest way is to let the requester create a temporary queue and let it be specified in the requests, in the "reply-to" property of the message, as depicted in this [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html).

The clients will reply filling the message with the local DB contents and sending a message to such a queue.

> So to retreive data from the client i will send a message to client's
>   listener and wait for response.

When dealing with messaging you never wait: you just "react to messages". The requester will be set up consuming messages from the "reply-to" queue. When a response arrive there, the requester will act consequently.